# Monitoring other Tomcat servers with zabbix

Tags: tomcat, server, remote-server, zabbix

Can I use Zabbix to monitor other Tomcat servers?

aws1 (Zabbix server) <-> aws2 (Tomcat server)

Please tell us how you can monitor.

Is it a way to use JMX and Gateway?
Please let me know if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

there is no problem to monitor different Tomcat servers on different hosts.

The "JMX queries" are sent from the Zabbix Server (Or a Zabbix Proxy if defined) to the Host+Port defined in the Hoset setup of Zabbix.

Of course your Tomcat JVM + Firewall must allow access from the Zabbix Server via the JMX Protocol (And you should not open it for the whole world)

If you have multiple Tomcat instances running on the same host, then you must specify different Ports for the JMX protocol, and in Zabbix also add multiple JMX templates which then use the other ports(s)

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor it of course, with Zabbix you can monitor everything. Please use this and the first one is the Official solution:

[Zabbix Tomcat Monitoring](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/tomcat)